# Cleaner way to change focus on child components in React

Tags: focus, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out a cleaner way to use arrow keys to move focus up and down in a list of inputs using React. The list is the parent component, the input the children. In order to figure out what input should be focused next, I'm giving each child a `ref` as well as a numeric `id` that I use to track ordering. When an arrow key is detected, the callback then finds the child with the correct `ref` and goes into that child's `refs` to grab the input and give it focus.

I'm new at React, this feels quite dirty, thus I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution.

Code and working jsfiddle:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    handleUp: function(e) {
        switch(e.key) {
            case "ArrowDown":
                this.props.handleFocus(this.props.id+1);
            break;
            case "ArrowUp":
                this.props.handleFocus(this.props.id-1);            
            break;
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div><input defaultValue={this.props.name} onKeyUp={this.handleUp} ref="input" /></div>;
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
    handleFocus: function(id) {
        var child = this.refs['child' + id];
        if (!child) return;
        var input = child.refs.input;
        input.getDOMNode().focus();
    },
    render: function() {
        var inputs = [];
        for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
            inputs.push(<Child key={i} id={i} name={"value" + i} handleFocus={this.handleFocus} ref={'child' + i} />);
        }
        return <div>
            {inputs}
        </div>;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/509/

Comment: For this particular scenario I really wanted to have arrow keys take action but in general yeah tabs are a good idea

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but none are really 'better' than this.

The alternatives would use a mixin, but that brings in the mental cost of black box abstraction for little gain.  I'd just keep it as is.

Comment: That seems fair enough. It mostly seems redundant to be declaring a separate `id` when both `ref` and `key` are there. Thanks!

Comment: you can abstract "some of that with something like:   handleFocus={ this.handleFocus.bind(i) }, and then in your handleFocus function accept an extra parameter to indicate the direction